# How to know if there is a file that has git commit changed since a certain date

Tags: git, shell, date

I want to write a script that finds if there is a file in a directory that has been changed by `git commit ...` since a particular date.

In the Groovy file, during one of the stages, it does tests, but I don't want to run the tests if the files haven't changed since the last time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -n "$(git log --since 'particular date' filename)" ]; then
    echo changed
fi
```

```
if [ -n "$(git shortlog --since 'particular date' filename0" ]; then
    echo changed
fi
```

Comment: I used:  # if no files are found to be older then $TIME_SPECIFIED 
 if [ -n "`git rev-list HEAD -n 1 --since==$TIME_SPECIFIED -- $LOCATION`" ]; then
  IS_FOUND=1
 fi